# How does the view filter: Search: Search Terms works? Can I improve it?

Tags: search, views

I have a View with and Exposed Filter: **Search: Search Terms** to filter the view result based in the keywords entered in this filter.

I works, but not as I expected.

Lets say I have a node with the title "The car, a good transport". Then:

- if I enter the keyword: **car** the node is shown
- if I enter the keywords: **car a good** the node is not shown
- if I enter the keywords: **good car**  the node is not shown

Is this behaviour right? I need the node to be shown in all these situations

**UPDATE**: I see that there is already an open issue about this: http://drupal.org/node/1615438

Comment: do you want that node "The car, a good transport" as result, if you enter anyone of above 3?

Comment: yes that is what I need

Comment: If you want to search nodes based on title alone, you can try with Node:title instead of Search:search terms in filter section and select the operator as "Contains any word".

Comment: good idea, but I also need to search into the body of the node.

Comment: @Sathiya Based in your idea I added the node:title and node:body and get it working. Do you mind to move your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to search nodes based on title alone, you can try with Node:title instead of Search:search terms in filter section and select the operator as "Contains any word"

Answer (score 0):

Search API allows the indexing of multiple fields. This would allow you to search both title and body fields.

Answer (score -1):

It's better to use operator "contains all words". Drupal search is no good, it's indexing everything but then you can't find anything..